# Как вертикально выровнять горизонтальный список относительно картинки

Tags: html, css

```css
.container ul {
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS: поддержка броузерами [display:flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex), [align-items](https://caniuse.com/#search=align-items)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так:

```html
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пункт-ссылка5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```